# Smoothing rotation with Quaternion.Lerp

Tags: unity-game-engine, quaternions

I'm trying to align my character with the ground by shooting a raycast downwards and aligning my characters rotation with grounds normal.

Here is a snippet:

```
RaycastHit hit;
Vector3 ray = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.down);

if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, ray, out hit)) {
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, hit.normal) * transform.rotation;
}
```

When I'm trying to smooth out that rotation tho, it seems to not be taking place at all.

This is how I'm trying to Lerp those values.

```
RaycastHit hit;
Vector3 ray = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.down);

if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, ray, out hit)) {
    quatTargetRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, hit.normal) * transform.rotation;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, hit.normal), 0.5f * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

quatTargetRotation is a class variable of the Quaternion class.

Comment: where are you calling this code? In the Update function? A coroutine?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm correct but `FromToRotation` sounds like it creates a displacement instead of your target rotation. Think of how vectors can be considered as either a point in space or a displacement. Also, it seems that you missed out the `* transform.rotation` on the Lerp line, which effectively rotates your character to the displacement rotation.

Comment: A function called by another that's called by Update, you can take a look of the whole script here: https://pastebin.com/8aspp3uf

Comment: Are yuo sure that `if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, ray, out hit))` is being evaluated as `true`?

Comment: Yeah it does evaluate to true @mayo

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(hit.normal), 0.5f);
```

It seems you are using `, 0.5f * Time.deltaTime);` as the `t` argument. That's not going to work, because: `t` needs to go from 0 to 1 over the time you want to reach the target rotation.

`0.5f * Time.deltaTime` will jiggle at some small value, differing every frame.

make a timer variable that survives Update() calls. a `public float timer = 0f;` for example. Then increase the value like `timer += Time.deltaTime`.

Alternative: use a constant value like `0.5f` - this rotates 50% of the difference every call. And that difference shrinks of course. So the rotation speed will slow down (may be desired for smooth rotation) but never 100% reach the target.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Comment: added more details